# Скрипты bash и подсветка вывода в консоль

Tags: bash, grep

Для поиска по odt документах пользовался командой

```
for f in *.odt; do echo $f; odt2txt "$f" | grep -i "Слово поиска"; done
```

Как и полагается, при выводе grep подсвечивал фразу поиска (светлым красным жирным). Сегодня решил перенести это в скрипт

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

for f in *.odt
do 
  echo $f 
  odt2txt "$f" | grep -i "$1"
done
```

По прежнему все работает, но фраза поиска почему-то не подсвечивается (все выводится стандартным шрифтом), как в случае одной команды из консоли. Почему, и как вернуть подсветку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

добавьте опцию `--color` со значением `always`

```
$ grep --color=always ...
```

подробности в `man grep`.

---

в первом описанном случае, вероятно, вызывается не программа *grep* напрямую, а *псевдоним* (*alias*) с дополнительными опциями (например, про тот же цвет). проверить можно так:

```
$ alias grep
```

Comment: Благодарю
$ alias grep
alias grep='grep --color=auto'